# The Additional Definition in Update Method in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

Hereby, I got message from previous email, below

```c#
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    ConnStr = "Data Source=FIN03;Initial Catalog=CmsTest;Integrated Security=True";
    cn = new SqlConnection(ConnStr);
    cn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = cn;
    mytran = cn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable );

    cmd.Transaction = mytran;
    try
        scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
        da.Update(ds, "tblworker");
        mytran.Commit ();
        MessageBox.Show("Data update successfully"); 
    catch (Exception err
           mytran.Rollback();
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message.ToString());
```

Please give  me more brief about definition :
- What is ds ?
- What is tblworker ?

I have done this command, it is in red-underline with Vb.net

Comment: That's certainly C# code lines (`private void` as clear indication, in VB.NET it is `Private Sub`). You need to provide VB.NET version.

Comment: It seems that you have copied and pasted C# code from the web into a VB project.  Of course you'll get all sorts of syntax errors.  There are numerous code converters online that will convert between C# and VB with varying levels of success.  You can also download Instant VB from Tangible Software Solutions to do a pretty much perfect job with even complex code.

Comment: You should do some reading on ADO.NET and the types and members involved so that you understand what this code is doing but, to answer your specific questions, `ds` would be a variable that refers to a `DataSet` and "tblworker" is the name of a `DataTable` it contains. That code is saving changes from that `DataTable` back to a database.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You posted your code and you don't know your own definitions?